# Inner CollectionView Shows EmptyView When using CollectionView inside CollectionView (Xamarin, Visual Studio 2019)

Tags: xamarin.forms, collectionview

Using the below code in `HomePage.xaml` file

When I use  only one `CollectionView` it properly shows product data but when used inside another collectionview it shows `EmptyView`

[image: Image Attached]

```xml
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}" EmptyView="Empty">
            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <LinearItemsLayout ItemSpacing="20" Orientation="Vertical">
                    
                </LinearItemsLayout>
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>    
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Frame BackgroundColor="Aqua" CornerRadius="40" >                           
                        <Grid Padding="10"  BackgroundColor="RosyBrown">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="200px"/>                  
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <CollectionView  ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" EmptyView="Nothing To Show">
                                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                            <Grid Padding="10"  BackgroundColor="Aqua">
                                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding ProductName}"/>
                                                <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding ProductDescription}"/>
                                                <Label Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding ProductPrice}"/>
                                                <Label Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding ProductImage}"/>

                                            </Grid>                        
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                            </CollectionView>
                        </Grid>   
                    </Frame>
                </DataTemplate>        
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate> 
        </CollectionView>

        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

I tried changing the orientation and other layout setting but it is not working.

Comment: you really should not try to nest collection views.  However, if you have to the problem is likely related to your VM, which you have not posted

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide the viewmodel code .